# Partition list into sub-lists, by property

Tags: python

I have the following partitioning function:

```
def group_by_name(data):
    names = set([entry.name for entry in data])  # detect all possible names
    # and now create a sublist for each possible name
    by_name = [[entry for entry in data if entry.name == name] for name in names]
    return by_name
```

Is there a more pythonic way of implementing this function?

### EDIT

The data:

```
import random


class Data:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

NAMES = [ 'jose', 'pedro', 'antonio', 'jesus', 'ricardo', 'anabel']

data = [Data(random.choice(NAMES)) for _ in range(100)]
```

Comment: A sharable instance of `data` would have been nice. Also, some tricks may be available depending on its type.

Comment: @Kanak data added

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is `O(N*K)` since you iterate the entire list as many times as there are distinct elements. You can collect the lists in a single iteration (`O(N)`), using e.g. the following pattern:

```
def group_by_name(data):
    d = {}
    for entry in data:
        d.setdefault(entry.name, []).append(entry)
    return list(d.values())
```

You could also have an `O(N*logN)` one-liner, using some utils:

```
from operator import attrgetter as ag
from itertools import groupby as gb

def group_by_name(data): 
    return [list(g) for _, g in gb(sorted(data, key=ag('name')), key=ag('name'))]
```

Comment: `setdefault` will greatly simplify my code! I was previously doing `if key not in d` to initialize the dicts ...

Comment: You can also use a `collections.defaultdict` to increase readablity further: `d=defaultdict(list)` and in the loop simply `d[entry.name].append(entry)`

Comment: Isn't `defaultdict` considerably slower than `dict`?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you notice a considerable difference. After all, it subclasses `dict` and effectively uses the same C code for most operations. I'd say in nearly all real world cases, the readability and therefore productivity/maintainability trumps the performance.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch "collect the lists in a single iteration" which is true. The list constructor for the return value does not iterate `data`, but `d` (`O(k)` if you will) which renders the entire process `O(n+k)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary and loop over the data,using name as key and a list of entry as value. Then put every key's value into a new constructed list then return it. More efficient as this is linear runtime.